# DDD - Domain Service with infrastructure implementation

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm implementing a project in DDD using hexagonal architecture.
I'm trying to follow all the best practise avoiding anemic Domain model but I came across this problem.
I have an entity Client that has a property priority, to calculate this priority I use a rest call to an external API. 
I'd like to avoid a setPriority method on the entity so I came out with this solution but I'm not sure it is actually "DDD compliant".
Here in pseudo code:

```
//DOMAIN
interface PriorityService {
  public int exec(Client client);
}

class Client {
....
  public void calculatePriority(PriorityService service) {
    this.priority = service.exec(this);
  }
}

//INFRASTRUCTURE
class ThirdPartyPriorityService implements PriorityService{
  ...
  public int exec(Client client) {
    int priority = this.externalApi(...);
    return priority; 
  }
}
```

I find this approach really simple and effective to integrate third party service, the entity is the sole responsible for the coherence of his internal state but I can integrate different systems with ease.
Is there a better way to do it (preferably without the usage of a setter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do it (preferably without the usage of a setter)?

Maybe.  Consider:

> Design is what we do to get more of what we want than we would get by just doing it -- Ruth Malan

Whether there is a "better way to do it" is going to depend on the "what we want" in your context.

When Eric Evans described [ddd](/questions/tagged/ddd) in 2003, one of the things he wanted was to separate the domain code from "the plumbing" -- we should be able to describe the business without our code being polluted by database strings, and transactions, and so on.

```
public void calculatePriority(PriorityService service) {
  this.priority = service.exec(this);
}
```

Riddle: how, in this design, do you deal with the fact that [the network is unreliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing)?  If your solution is going to be resilient, then you are going to need logic somewhere that ensures that the system behaves gracefully when the network is unavailable, the remote server is offline for maintenance, credentials go stale, and so on....

Expressing that same idea a different way: fetching an HTTP response from a web server is I/O, and I/O "contaminates" everything that touches it.  Therefore `ThirdPartyPriorityService` is I/O, therefore `Client::calculatePriority` is I/O.

Same idea again: our HTTP client necessarily lives in the "imperative shell" ([Bernhardt 2012](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell)), and by injecting the client into our domain code, we are in effect making our domain code part of the imperative shell.

An alternative approach is to recognize that `ThirdPartyPriorityService` is retrieving information_ from some remote location, and maybe that concern really belongs in the application, rather than in the domain -- your domain code cares about what the information is, but not where it came from.

So you could, for example, change your implementation so that the application invokes the priority service, then passes the priority to the domain model.  See [Cory Benfield's 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cC3_jGwl_U) on protocol libraries.

Designing your code this way isn't better or worse than the other; it's a different set of tradeoffs.

> if we failed to make our program align with what we then understood to be the proper way to think about our financial objects, then we were gonna continually stumble over that disagreement and that would slow us down -- [Ward Cunningham, 2009](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqeJFYwnkjE&t=27s)

If the code actually works the way you think it works when you aren't looking at it, your estimates about changing it are likely to be better.  That might be a valuable "what we want".

Comment: thank you for your answer. I omitted a large part of the codebase and actually there are some mapping between infrastructureException into Domain Exception also I have a fallback strategy but I left it out because my main concert was to preserve the Domain Model consistency and find out if this approach violate the "DDD purity if my architecture"